# extjs - embedded objects/names in forms

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs4

I currently use multiple objects to populate parts of a extjs form using `setValues()`. Ex:

```
someForm.getForm().setValues({prop1: foo});
```

Is there a way I could name the elements of my form `object1.prop1`, `object2.prop2` ect. so that I could do  single `someForm.getForm().setValues({object1: object1, object2: object2, ...})`? i.e. the embedded objects would be parsed out.

Additionally, is there a way to intercept the upload before the `POST` to map (`object1.prop1`, `object1.prop2`, `...`) --> `object1: {prop1: *, prop2: *, ...}` ?

This would make it much easier than having to do something like mapping `object1.prop1` --> `object1_prop1` -> `object1.prop1`

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: No, currently there's no way to do that.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli would you recommend a mapping as proposed at the end? I.e, map the `.` selector to `_`'s, then on upload, map back and aggregate objects? i.e. ( `obj1: {p1: *, p2: *}` --> `obj1_p1: *`, `obj1_p2: *` --> `obj1.p1: *`, `obj1.p2: *` --> `obj1: {p1: *, p2: *}` )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do so but the way is different than the one you have specified in question.
There would be two scenarios :

1) You have a form(suppose modify), and you make a request to server to get the data.
What you can do is create a model with assigned name to the form fields. And assign the model to form with values from server. See below e.g.

```
// define StudentModel with fields firstName, lastName, address, and so on....
// form with fields, please have field attribute 'name' with values defined in model
// e.g. {xtype : 'textfield', name: 'firstName'}, {xtype : 'textfield', name: 'lastName'}, and so on
var form = this.getForm();
form.reader = Ext.create('Ext.data.reader.Json',{ // Use XML reader if you are using XML response.
    success: '@success',
    model: 'StudentModel'
});

form.load({ // load method will load data automatically from server to form fields
    url: '/getStudentData',
    params:{        
        studentId: 24
    }
});
```

2) Other scenario is you have data available locally(suppose in array or variables) and you want to assign that data to form,
Create a record with StudentModel as below, and assign record to form :

```
var record = Ext.create('StudentModel', {
    firstName: 'Nandkumar',
    lastName: 'Tekale',
    address: 'RH 26, some street, city'
});

form.loadRecord(record); // You are done, all values to form are assigned.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've investigated both possibilities, but both don't necessarily address my problem; that is needing **multiple** objects/models to fill the form. I can't strip the namespace of the top-level objects, because that may result in naming collisions. I.e. If I fill my form using a `StudentModel` as you proposed *and* a `ProffModel` that may share field names (`firstName`, `lastName`, ...)

Comment: Then in that case you might have to assign value to individual field. If you are having more than two models per form, you might be leading to inconsistency in design I guess.

Comment: Also in the case of embedded objects. I.e. `{a: {b:*, c:*}, d: {e:*, f:*}}`. Neither option allows parsing of `b, c, e, f` to form elements and then back into the original object structure