# Calling a function from component definition

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

Just a simple question, is it possible to call an ExtJS function to be able to set default value when we are defining a component like below? Because, when I tried below, the function doesn't assign the value.

```
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  fieldLabel: 'DNR TYPE',
  name: 'DNR_TYPE,
  value: Ext.getCmp('dnr-type').getRawValue() 
  // here is the function that I want to call and assign the value
}
```

**EDIT :**

Dear friends, I found the problem which is related with form render. When application startup, the form initialized with default values. Therefore, the field value returning empty. When user select a record from the combobox, I should assign that value to related textfield.

Now, is there any method to refresh/reload form again when user select a record from the form?

Comment: Why not just try it and see if it works?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work! I wanted to know that am I doing something wrong.

Comment: You need to put together a working test case. You're talking about code that isn't referenced anywhere in what you posted.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I found the problem. The form panel rendered before users select a record from the combobox. Therefore, the value didn't assign the field. Are there any method the refresh/reload the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that you can try is :

```
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  fieldLabel: 'DNR TYPE',
  name: 'DNR_TYPE,
  listeners: {
    beforerender: function() {
       this.setValue(Ext.getCmp('dnr-type').getRawValue());
    }
  }
}
```

If `Ext.getCmp('dnr-type').getRawValue()` returns value, it will be assigned to textfield, otherwise if it is blank string then textfield will contain blank value and you wouldn't see value in textfield.

### EDIT:

> When user select a record from the combobox, I should assign that value to related textfield.

----> you can change value of textfield on `select` event of `combo` like :

```
{
    xtype: 'combo'
    displayField: 'foo',
    valueField: 'bar',
    lsiteners: {
       select: function( combo, records) {
          var rec = records[0]; // records will contain selected records(1 or more)
          var textField = // get textfield using Ext.getCmp()
          textField.setValue(rec.get('modelName'));
       }
    }
}
```

> Now, is there any method to refresh/reload form again when user select a record from the form?

----> I am not clear with this. May be I can help you with this if you tell me the scenario

Comment: I edited the question, if you don't mind could you please check?

Comment: Dear Nandkumar, realy I hate this project because they do not know what they want. The application has 3 card layout. When user start the process, filling necessary informations step by step from first card. At the end of the process, in last card layout, I should display a summary what they did. The problem raising in last card layout because there is another form to show selected records.

Comment: I can understand. That's why proper architecture is necessary, I am going through the same but I love my project and changes because it is never hectic to me. :) BTW, if you have `record`, you can assign record directly to form using `form.loadRecord(record)` provided field's `name` should be the field name in record.

Comment: Also see this [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646585/extjs-embedded-objects-names-in-forms/18651131#18651131) for `form.loadRecord(record)` demonstration

Answer (score 0):

as long as Ext.getCmp('dnr-type').getRawValue() returns a string its possible...

Comment: instead of getCmp use
.getForm().findField('dnr-type').getRawValue();