# Extjs 4.1 - How to load array to formpanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a window that has items like

```
items:{
        xtype:'form',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            fieldLabel: '1',
            name: 'va[]'
        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: '2',
            name: 'va[]'
        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: '3',
            name: 'va[]'
        }]
    },
```

I using load form to get data from server to my form

```
    var form = win.down('form').getForm();
    form.load({         
        url: 'load.php',
        success:function(form, action){
            win.show();         
        }
    });
```

My json look like

```
{"success":true,"data":{"va":["1","2","3"]}}
```

But my form after load success then that is blank (value is not set)

How to do that thank

Comment: You will need to modify your json and provide different names to fields, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18651131/1065180)

Comment: @NandkumarTekale b/c items in my form is dynamic and if i use clear name then that's difficult to manager :|.

Answer (score 1):

Though the `action` you have access to the `response`. Then you can get your data and assign it manually. You will probably need a unique `itemId` since all your fields have the same name. Something like:

```
form.load({
  url: 'load.php',
  success: function(form, action) {
    var me = this,
        data, i;
    try {
      data = Ext.decode(action.response.responseText);
      console.log(data); //outputs data.success, data.data.va in your console.
      if(data.data && Ext.isArray(data.data.va)) {
        for(i = 0; i < data.va.length; i++) {
          //here do your logic to populate the fields...
        } 
      }
    }catch(e){}
  }
});
```